# How do I persist local changes to NopCommerce docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nopcommerce

I am running a NopCommerce installation for theme development locally via Docker.

I have everything running smoothly now but I can't change local code to affect my live container.

I have my local theme files linked to my container via volumes but my changes only show when I make them, stop the docker container, and restart the docker container. I can confirm that the code does change when I restart but I need to work on a live container with live code.

I have this working with Wordpress theme development but I can't figure out why NopCommerce doesn't want me to do this.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    nopcommerce_web:
        image: "nopcommerceteam/nopcommerce:4.20"
        container_name: nopcommerce
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - nopcommerce_data:/app
            - ./Themes:/app/Themes
        depends_on:
           - nopcommerce_database
    nopcommerce_database:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
        container_name: nopcommerce_mssql_server
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "fakepassword"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
            MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
        volumes:
            - nopcommerce_db:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  nopcommerce_db:
  nopcommerce_data:
```

Comment: You mean that the data in the folder ./Themes: are gone after a restart?

Comment: Not gone but if I make a change while the container is running, to see the change in the project I have to stop and start the container.

Comment: So far I've seen that any nop commerce plugins or themes added or changed do require nopCommerce to be restarted.  This has been true even when I'm not running in a container.